# Angular: add a multi provider from lazy feature module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I have an ErrorModule (eager) configured as follows:

```
export const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<ErrorConfig[]>('Module errors configuration.');


@NgModule({
  imports: [... ]
})
export class ErrorModule {
  static forRoot(config: ErrorConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ErrorModule,
      providers: [
        ErrorService,
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: CONFIG, useValue: config, multi: true }
      ]
    };
  }

  static forChild(config: ErrorConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ErrorModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: CONFIG, useValue: config, multi: true }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Core module then imports `ErrorModule` as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ErrorModule.forRoot(ERROR_CONFIG)
  ], ...
```

**Lazy** loaded child feature module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ErrorModule.forChild(ERROR_CONFIG_CHILD)
  ], ...
```

**I would like to see both configurations `ERROR_CONFIG` and `ERROR_CONFIG_CHILD` injected into `ErrorService` defined in ErrorModule**:

```
@Injectable
export class ErrorService {
    constructor(@Inject(CONFIG) private readonly errorConfigs: ErrorConfig[])
}
```

But the service's `errorConfigs` (in constructor) contains only `CONFIG` defined in `core.module` - the one defined in `forRoot()` function (An array with one element).

*Lazy feature module has been loaded and initialized and the `ErrorModule.forChild(...)` invoked*

It kind of makes sense that the `ErrorService` has been constructed in time when only core module's `CONFIG` injection token was available - the feature module has not beeen loaded yet.

I have also tried to import the `CONFIG` using Angular `Injector` outside of constructor (method in `ErrorService`) and the result was same.

```
const configs: any[] = injector.get(CONFIG); // returns only root CONFIG
```

So my question is: Is it possible to somehow access a provider provided by a lazy module in app module? (Access it in app's root injector?)

Comment: Did you find an alternative? I'd like to implement basically the same thing, pluggable features. This does not seem to be feasible through DI at a first glance, and I'm not really surprised nor deceived. But it's too bad that this gonna end up with a singleton service you can register to (in a non-declarative or IoC way).

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling see my answer bellow - an alterative.

Comment: @Felix @MorganTouvereyQuilling Do you guys think we should implement this use case like in `@angular/router` module? I still haven't unraveled the "black magic" done in the router config loader though. 

• [router module](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L258)

• [router config loader](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_config_loader.ts)

Comment: Did you ever find an 'angular-way' solution for this? I basically need the same thing

Comment: @devqon I used the solution below. I have no angular-way solution.

Comment: @GlennMohammad I wanted to do exactly the same. Angular team does this for Rotuer, so it is somehow possible. But I can't understand what's the magic behind it. Any luck on your side?

Comment: @gigaDIE Nope – it was a dead-end.  In fact, I've not been using Angular since 2020. Perhaps it could be asked in their official GH issues channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with a solution, that uses `ErrorService` defined in `CoreModule` to register configurations when `FeatureModule` is initialized:

```
import { ErrorService } from '@core/error.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule, ForFeatureModule, TranslateModule.forChild() ],
    declarations: [FeatureModule],
    providers: []
})
export class FeatureModule {
    constructor(
        private readonly translate: TranslateService, private readonly errorService: ErrorService) {
        translate.setTranslation('cz', i18n, true);

        // --- HERE --- errorService configures global error configuration
        errorService.addErrorMappings('FEATURE1', ERROR_MAPPING);
    }
}
```