# Angular register dependencies from feature module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to register dependencies from a feature loaded module and I can't figure out how to use these dependencies from other modules. I don't think that it's not possible at all since all the information exists on the client.

I've created a stackblitz to reproduce: [Stackblitz implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbxx3f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustomers%2Fcustomer-list%2Fcustomer-list.component.ts)

Clicking on count shows the amount of registered dependencies of type `EXCEPTION_FORMATTER`. Clicking on "Orders" loads a feature module with a dependency. Clicking count again still only findes one dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not something that can be done if you use Lazy-loading.

If you need providers as "multiple" in cascade (access parent and child providers in child module), [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18894) can help you.
I did an update of your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbxx3f-p3kxvr?file=src%2Fapp%2Finject.module.ts) to make you an example.

If you need to access child registred providers from the parent, you will need to do it another way has mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263603/angular-add-a-multi-provider-from-lazy-feature-module). You can use a singleton that contains an array of "callback" where you can add or remove some of them.

Comment: I haven't found a solution for this, too. But why _shouldn't_ this be possible? All the information required is stored on the client. But yes, singleton services is probably the way to go.

Comment: I think the main problem is that we cannot give a `providedIn:"root"` config when we create a provider using a token (and multi flag).

Comment: Ok, so that is the most satisfying answer for now. Opened a feature request on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/39414

Answer (score 0):

You can search a solution with the forRoot pattern : https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern

And after try to do something inspired by this :

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/aa9bf1a1ed04020d1b9dba70f939de248a6238b1/modules/store/src/store_module.ts

with forRoot() forFeature() static module functions, the great Ngrx store library can increment the current store when a lazy module load a feature store module. Only after the lazy module is loaded, you can use the newly loaded store by other lazy loaded modules.